# How to cancel a mongoose query in a 'pre' hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am implementing some kind of caching for my 'find' queries on a certain schemas, and my cache works with the pre\post query hooks.

The question is how can I cancel the 'find' query correctly?

```
mySchema.pre('find', function(next){
    var result = cache.Get();

    if(result){
       //cancel query if we have a result from cache
       abort();
    } else {
       next();
    } 
});
```

so that this promise will be fulfilled?

```
Model.find({..})
        .select('...')
        .then(function (result) {
            //We can reach here and work with the cached results
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a reasonable solution to this myself for another non-caching reason but if your own specific caching method isn't too important I'd recommend you look at [mongoose-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-cache), works well and has simple settings thanks to it's dependency: [node-lru-cache](https://github.com/isaacs/node-lru-cache#options), check that out for more options.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check out mongoose validators, that seems like a better way to handle controlling whether or not an object gets created.

You can create a custom validate function that will throw an error in the Model.save function, causing it to fail. Here is a code snippet from the docs:

```
// make sure every value is equal to "something"
function validator (val) {
  return val == 'something';
}
new Schema({ name: { type: String, validate: validator }});

// with a custom error message

var custom = [validator, 'Uh oh, {PATH} does not equal "something".']
new Schema({ name: { type: String, validate: custom }});

// adding many validators at a time

var many = [
    { validator: validator, msg: 'uh oh' }
  , { validator: anotherValidator, msg: 'failed' }
]
new Schema({ name: { type: String, validate: many }});

// or utilizing SchemaType methods directly:

var schema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });
schema.path('name').validate(validator, 'validation of {PATH} failed with value {VALUE}');
```

Found that here if you want to look into it more. Hope that helps someone!

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate